# Wi-Fi adapter not found. Wireless doesn't work: RTL8822CE Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, xubuntu, network-manager

I faced the problem after an issues with sudoers.so file.

NetworkManager logs:

[image: NetworkManager logs:]

dkms status tree:

[image: dkms status tree:]

kernel version:

[image: kernel version]

For no reason `lsmod | grep rtw` didn't show anything in the console.
Also `nmcli` returns this.

nmcli command:

[image: nmcli command]

lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list:

[image: lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list]

I already wasted a day an night trying to solve this problem. Does anyone may know solution?

UPD: more info
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/VjVHqxGx7K/

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in UEFI and try afgain.

Comment: @ChanganAuto didn't work, unfortunately :( But thanks, for idea :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: @waltinator Hey there. Didn't try. Gimme a minute, please.

Comment: @waltinator nope, there were no answers ;(
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/VjVHqxGx7K/